Speed up For each VBA
I am using the below VBA code for 88K lines.  Due to the number of lines, it is moving very slow. It is supposed to determine if there is a zero beginning in cell D17 and place the message "OK - No Differences" in the next cell.   How do you suggest speeding this up? See code below.
Sub Addtext()
Dim lrow As Long, cell As Range
lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("D17:D" & lrow)
    If cell.Value = 0 Then
     cell.Offset(0, 1) = "OK - No Differences"
     End If
Next cell
Application.screen = False
End Sub


Please, try the next code. It will be very fast, even for large ranges, using an array, working mostly in memory and dropping the processed array content, at once, at the end of the code:
Sub AddtextArray()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lrow As Long, arr, i As Long

 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lrow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).row
 arr = ws.Range("D17:E" & lrow).Value2

 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) = 0 Then arr(i, 2) = "OK - No Differences"
 Next i
 
 'drop the processed array content, at once:
 ws.Range("D7").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value2 = arr
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Hi - It looks like your macro begins in D7 while mine begins in D17.  D17 is part of a pivot.  Is there any adjustment to be done for this?

@Fred Blair 7 should be changed with 17. Edited and adapted the code.

I am always using this approach and I can confirm it is the fastest (as long as looping in a single array).

@Peace You can also use two arrays. This choice is based on the need you have, respectively: In this very case I thought that he may be needing the previous existing "OK - No Differences". If he does not need them it would be better to choose two such arrays, each of them containing a single column. Both of them being Redim in the same way, I such a case all previous marks will be deleted and only the second array content will be dropped in the "D:D" column...

Flag Column Matches

Sub FlagColumn()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const FLAG_YES As String = "OK - No Differences"
    Const FLAG_NO As Variant = Empty
    Const MATCH_NUMBER As Long = 0
    
    ' Reference the objects (workbook, worksheet, ranges).
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = ws.Range("D17", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns("E")
    
    ' Return the source values in an array.
    
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim Data() As Variant:
    
    If RowsCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        Data = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the array and replace the matches
    ' with the 'yes' flag, and the mismatches with the 'no' flag.
    
    Dim Value As Variant, r As Long, IsFound As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        IsFound = False
        Value = Data(r, 1)
        If VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then
            If Value = MATCH_NUMBER Then IsFound = True
        End If
        If IsFound Then Data(r, 1) = FLAG_YES Else Data(r, 1) = FLAG_NO
    Next r
    
    ' Return the values of the array in the destination range.
    
    drg.Value = Data
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Column flagged.", vbInformation

End Sub

